# How To Add This Format Function In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a call in AngularJS to $http Get which is returning data.  I have a boolean field PassFail that currently appears as "true" or "false".  I want it to display "Pass" or "Fail".  I've tried adding a PassFail function in $scope and $rootScope but nothing works for me.  I think there is some easy solution but it will probably take me days to figure this out on my own.  Can you help?

```js
    var oApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    oApp.controller("certificationsCtrl", function ($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.Exams = {};

        $scope.GetPassFail = function (passFail)
        {
            return passFail ? "Pass" : "Fail";
        };

        $scope.ShowExams = function (certificationID)
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:49861/api/Exams?id=" + certificationID + "&extra=0";

          $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url
            }).then(function mySuccess(response)
            {
                $scope.Exams = response.data;
            }, function myError(response)
            {
                alert("error response.statusText = " + response.statusText);
            });
        }
    });

<tr ng-repeat="x in Exams">
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.ExamNumber}}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.ExamShortName }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.PassFail | GetPassFail }}</td>
MM-dd" }}</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't process this inside html with

```
{{ x.PassFail ? "Pass" : "Fail" }}
```

Comment: Both answers work, and while Kethansri answered my question more directly, I think we would all agree this is a better solution.  Simpler is almost always better.  Thanks Simon.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{GetPassFail(x.PassFail)}}</td>`